# Is there a method to split an array of objects into groups?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have an array of objects with some sort of groupable key:

```
var people = [
    { 'name':'Alice',   'gender': 'female' },
    { 'name':'Bob',     'gender': 'male'   },
    { 'name':'Jeremy',  'gender': 'male'   },
    { 'name':'Jess',    'gender': 'female' },
    { 'name':'Seymour', 'gender': 'female' },
];
```

Is there a (native) function/method that can be applied to the array to 'unzip' the array into two arrays, like so:

```
boysAndGirls = people.[**something**]('gender');
```

That could result in:

```
{
   'male': [ ... ],
   'female': [ ... ]
}
```

or even:

```
[
  [ {Bob, ...}, {Jeremy, ...}, {Seymour, ...} ], // 'males' array
  [ {Alice, ...}, {Jess, ...} ] // 'female' array
]
```

I could write this algorithm myself, but I really just want to know if there is a native array method -- or one that might exist in another language that could be polyfilled in?

Comment: No, there's no built-in Javascript function for this.

Comment: Maybe a library like underscore.js has something that does it.

Comment: It's really simple to make a loop create this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method in JavaScript. Ruby has it in [`Enumerator#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
people.group_by { |person| person['gender'] }
```

and it is easy enough to write in JavaScript as well. In fact, some libraries have it already, e.g. [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy).

```
_.groupBy(people, function(person) {
  return person['gender'];
});
```

If you write it yourself, you can customise it a bit:

```
function groupByProp(array, prop) {
  var result = {};
  array.forEach(function(item) {
    var val = item[prop];
    if (!result[val]) result[val] = [item];
    else result[val].push(item);
  });
  return result;
}
groupByProp(people, 'gender');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const groupByAge = users.reduce((p,c) =>{
    const genKey = Math.floor(c.age/10);
    const key = `${genKey}0- ${genKey}9`;
    if(!p[key]){
        p[key] =[];
    }
    p[key].push(c);
    return p;
}, {})

console.log(groupByAge);
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score -1):

There is not a native Javascript function for this but you can use the following code:

```js
var originalArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

var splitArray = function (arr, size) {

  var arr2 = arr.slice(0),
      arrays = [];

  while (arr2.length > 0) {
      arrays.push(arr2.splice(0, size));
  }

  return arrays;
}

splitArrays = splitArray(originalArray, 2);

console.log(splitArrays);
```

Answer (score -2):

The nearest thing I can think of off the top of my head for a native solution is to use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). It's not as simple as what you are looking for but it works:

```
var boysAndGirls = people.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  obj[item.gender].push(item.name);
  return obj;
}, {male: [], female: []});
```

Comment: Someone clicked an arrow. Now - *why* it was downvoted, I am not sure; it's not elegant, but it does work.

Comment: Yeah for pandatics! :-P I disagree on the elegance as it is readable and easy to understand what each line does. However, elegance is subjective.